# Responsive bootstrap nav with a brand logo in the middle

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, centering, responsive

I want a responsive navbar with 4 links and a brand logo in the middle. I want the navbar centered in the middle of the browser. But I'm having trouble executing that layout.
How can I achieve it?

```css
.navbar-header {
  min-height: 150px;
}
.navbar {
  background: transparent;
  min-height: 113px;
  top: 0px;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: auto;
  border: none;
  padding: 0px 0px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #fff;
}
.navbar-brand {
  padding: 0 15px;
  height: 113px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav {
    position: relative;
    right: -50%;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li {
    position: relative;
    left: -50%;
  }
  .navbar-nav > li a {
    line-height: 113px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0 24px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .navbar-nav > li a {
    padding: 0 48px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .navbar-nav > li a {
    padding: 0 68px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Navigation ein-/ausblenden</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg" href="#">
        <img src="images/brand.png" alt="Brand" width="310" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Start</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Idee</a>
        </li>
        <li class="hidden-xs">
          <a href="#">
            <img src="images/brand.png" alt="Brand" width="310" />
          </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Leistungen</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help

```css
.navbar-header {
 min-height: 150px;
    }
    .navbar {
 background: transparent;
 min-height: 113px;
 top: 0px;
 font-size: 18px;
 width: auto;
 border: none;
 padding: 0px 0px;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
 color: #fff;
    }
    .navbar-brand {
 padding: 0 15px;
 height: 113px;
    }
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-nav {
 position: relative;
 right: -50%;
    }
    .navbar-nav > li {
 position: relative;
 left: -50%;
    }
    .navbar-nav > li a {
 line-height: 113px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 padding: 0 24px;
     } 
    }
    @media (min-width: 992px) {
    .navbar-nav > li a {
 padding: 0 48px;
     } 
    }
    @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .navbar-nav > li a {
 padding: 0 68px;
     } 
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container-fluid text-center">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
       <span class="sr-only">Navigation ein-/ausblenden</span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg" href="#"><img src="images/brand.png" alt="Brand" width="310"/></a>
     </div>
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li><a href="#">Start</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Idee</a></li>
       <li class="hidden-xs"><a href="#"><img src="images/brand.png" alt="Brand" width="310" /></a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Leistungen</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. But it dosent work :(

Comment: What did you change? @Freeces What doesn't work about it?

Comment: Just wrapped your `navbar` with `container-fluid` having class `text-center`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to don't edit bootstrap styles, use your own class.

```
.navbar-brand {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}
```